# axioms of probability identities explanation trick

Tags: probability

when does $P(A \cup B) = 1 - P(A \cap B)$

so I saw a problem that making a system

$P(S \ge 400)= P(X_1 \ge 400) \cup P(X_2 \ge 400) ....$

$= 1 - P(X_1\lt 400) \cap P(X_2\lt 400) ....$

Comment: **HINT** Re-check your work.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can use the probably familiar 
$$\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$$
to answer the question.

Alternately, you can use a Venn Diagram.

Comment: so would that mean $Pr (A \cup B) = 1 - Pr(A \cap B)$ if A and B are all the possible events in the venn diagram?

Comment: It would mean that the condition holds precisely if $\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)=1$. That can happen in many ways. Two extremes: (i) $B$ is the complement of $A$ and (ii) $A=B$, and each has probability $1/2$.